# Gridview dropdownlist item to a textbox upon selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a list of printed results.
Each row has an additional button to reprint and a reprint reason is needed.
I am manually storing the dropdownlist items in the aspx file as below:

```
                <asp:GridView SkinID="gridviewSkinmspgate" ID="grdPrintConfirmation" 
                Width="400px" runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                OnRowCommand="grdPrintConfirmation_RowCommand" 
                >
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Label Spec Ref" ControlStyle-Width="100px" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblSpecRef" runat="server" 
                    text='<%#Eval("GeneratedLabelForPrint.LabelSpecRef")%>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Printer Name" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="PrinterName" runat="server" 
                    text='<%#Eval("GeneratedLabelForPrint.PrinterName")%>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Print Successful" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="IsPrintSuccessful" runat="server" 
                    text='<%#Eval("IsPrintSuccessful")%>' ></asp:Label>       
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Reprint Count" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ReprintCount" runat="server" 
                    text='<%#Eval("ReprintCount")%>' ></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reprint Reason" ControlStyle-Width="150px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlReason">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="(Please Select)" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Printer not working" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Printer out of paper" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reprint" ControlStyle-Width="150px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
                    ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                    CommandName="btnReprint" Text="Submit Reprint" />
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
```

With the code above, each row has dropdownlist that has the 3 items below:
1. Printer not working
2. Printer out of paper
3. Other

I'm wondering how do I upon select "Other", on the UI, it will change to a textbox for the user to key in any other reason.

Comment: You mean on select "other" in dropdownlist , this box will change to text box ?

Comment: Which code you write in RowCommand event ?

Comment: rowcommand event currently facilitate the btnReprint which will take values from the row (inclusive of the "reprint reason").

Comment: Can you write whole code in comment ?

Comment: This is no longer needed. We are going to create a administration screen to add in reprint reasons instead of having the user add in on the client. Thank you for your time Jayesh.